# Simple fopen request not working with specific rss feed

Tags: php, curl, rss, simplexml, fopen

This request

```
file_get_contents('https://trade.4over.com');
```

Does not work on my `site5.com` shared server but does work on my local server.

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://trade.4over.com): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in [dir] online [line#] Other RSS feeds don't have this issue only this specific one.

PHP Config has `allow_url_fopen` turned on.

Curl Requests and `simpleXML` requests also fail on web server but not on local server.

Also tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($data);
```

Above code prints nothing. Blank screen with no error.

Comment: How about adding your code?

Comment: Hi Kaylined, file_get_contents() is the entire code. Also what is under "Also Tried"

Answer (score 0):

the connection timeout indicates that its not a problem with your app or php, much more likley with your environment. are there any firewalls, proxies, etc. which could block your request?

try a plain curl request from your commandline:

```
$ curl https://trade.4over.com/
```

and see if you have any problems.

Comment: Using Terminal on the local machine the plain curl request works correctly. But sing SSH on the shared server I get: curl: (7) Failed to connect to trade.4over.com port 443: Connection timed out

Comment: ok, then you defenitly have a network issue. try to ping the url ($ ping trade.4over.com). if this doesn't work either, you have to contact your admin/provider, whoever is responsible for your network.

Comment: I can't ping through the shared server, but trying basic curl commands it looks like I'm having the same issue with the entire trade.4over.com domain not just the RSS feed. I'm creating a support ticket with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says this is a network problem, not an application level one (i.e. **not** PHP/curl etc.). As I can not access this URL either, this is likely the remote server/server's network provider issue, not your shared server.

Why is it working for you local server? Two options: by some chance there is internet routing between you and 4over.com; or you have an entry for that hostname in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) which resolves to a correct IP address.

Comment: There's no internal routing here to 4over.com. If you use the demo on simplepie.org it reads the feed perfectly fine.